# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, replace, insert, indexing

```
PizzaChange=float(input("What would you like the new price for all standard pizzas to be? "))      
PriceList[0][1][2][3][4][5][6]=[PizzaChange]  
PriceList[7][8][9][10][11]=[PizzaChange+3]
```

Basically, I have an input that a user will put a number values (float input) into, then it will set all of these aforementioned list indexes to that value. For some reason I can't get it to set them without coming up with a:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

error. Am I doing something wrong or am I just looking at it the wrong way?

Comment: What line is generating the error?

Comment: I get the same error : `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable` in this line: `print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[0], scores[0]*100))` from this code: https://machinelearningmastery.com/evaluate-performance-deep-learning-models-keras/ What is wrong??

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`PriceList[0]` is a float. `PriceList[0][1]` is trying to access the first element of a float.  Instead, do

```
PriceList[0] = PriceList[1] = ...code omitted... = PriceList[6] = PizzaChange
```

or

```
PriceList[0:7] = [PizzaChange]*7
```

Comment: a slice from 0 to 7 has 7 elements, not 6.

Answer (score 5):

```
PriceList[0][1][2][3][4][5][6]
```

This says: go to the 1st item of my collection `PriceList`.  That thing is a collection; get its 2nd item.  That thing is a collection; get its 3rd...

Instead, you want *slicing*:

```
PriceList[:7] = [PizzaChange]*7
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PizzaChange=float(input("What would you like the new price for all standard pizzas to be? "))      
for i,price in enumerate(PriceList):
  PriceList[i] = PizzaChange + 3*int(i>=7)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not selecting multiple indexes with PriceList[0][1][2][3][4][5][6] , instead each [] is going into a sub index.

Try this

```
PizzaChange=float(input("What would you like the new price for all standard pizzas to be? "))      
PriceList[0:7]=[PizzaChange]*7  
PriceList[7:11]=[PizzaChange+3]*4
```

Comment: The problem with this is it replaces those index with only one value. For example I want List=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] to eqaul when I put say 3 in my input List=[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,7,8,9,10,11].

Comment: see my edit above, just multiply by the number of items you are replacing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to set elements 0 through 11 of PriceList to new values. The syntax would usually look like this:

```
prompt = "What would you like the new price for all standard pizzas to be? "
PizzaChange = float(input(prompt))
for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]: PriceList[i] = PizzaChange
for i in [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]: PriceList[i] = PizzaChange + 3
```

If they are always consecutive ranges, then it's even simpler to write:

```
prompt = "What would you like the new price for all standard pizzas to be? "
PizzaChange = float(input(prompt))
for i in range(0, 7): PriceList[i] = PizzaChange
for i in range(7, 12): PriceList[i] = PizzaChange + 3
```

For reference, `PriceList[0][1][2][3][4][5][6]` refers to "Element 6 of element 5 of element 4 of element 3 of element 2 of element 1 of element 0 of `PriceList`. Put another way, it's the same as `((((((PriceList[0])[1])[2])[3])[4])[5])[6]`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Because I set the number with a decimal part to `MinMoneyValidator()` and `MaxMoneyValidator()` respectively in `MoneyField()` with [Django-money](https://github.com/django-money/django-money),  as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
from djmoney.models.validators import MinMoneyValidator, MaxMoneyValidator 

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = MoneyField( # Here
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, default_currency='USD',
        validators=[        # Here                    # Here
            MinMoneyValidator(0.00), MaxMoneyValidator(999.99),
        ]
    )
```

So, I set the number without a decimal part to `MinMoneyValidator()` and `MaxMoneyValidator()` respectively in `MoneyField()` as shown below, then the error above was solved:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
from djmoney.models.validators import MinMoneyValidator, MaxMoneyValidator

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = MoneyField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, default_currency='USD',
        validators=[       # Here                 # Here
            MinMoneyValidator(0), MaxMoneyValidator(999),
        ]
    )
```