# 'float' object is not subscriptable to add to array

Tags: python

I'm coding for a project at school (GCSEs) and we have been tasked that the user will enter the value of a population and we have to code a program where python displays a model to show the population after a set number of generations. 
Once the user has entered their desired values I need to display it in a table-like format that shows the generation number an the population to the respective age range (juvenile, adult, senile).
To make the table I used an array but defined it earlier at the beginning of the code. When I try to append the values to the code I get this error ''float' object is not subscriptable'

this is my code of me trying to add to the array:

```
def run_model():

    print ("*"*10, "Running the Model", "*"*10)
    time.sleep(2)

    for x in range (1, gen_no):
        if(x !=0):
            juve_values.append ( float(adult_pop[x-1])*birth_rate)
            adult_values.append ( float(juve_pop[x-1])*juve_suv)
            senile_values.append ( float(sen_pop[x-1])*sen_suv+adult_pop[x-1]*adult_suv)

    for y in range (1, gen_no):
       print(str(juve_pop[y]) + " "*5 + str(adult_pop[y]) + " "*5 + str(sen_pop[y]))
```

when you answer please make it as basic as possible as I'm not an advanced coder.

Thanks

Comment: "it won't look believable when I had in my work" - are you asking us to write code that you'll just dump into your homework verbatim?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991591/typeerror-float-object-is-not-subscriptable

Comment: What is the type of `adult_pop`, `juve_pop` and `sen_pop`?

Comment: no i'm just asking what could i do to solve it because this is just one portion of my work that i can't seem to understand and my classmates don't undertstand. also the intent behind my clause is that if the coding is too complicated for me to understand and i put it in without knowing what it means because it is too complicated then that is just me plagiarising your work

Comment: adult_pop, juve_pop, sen_pop are variables that the user enters the value for

Comment: Yes, but what is the _type_, as I asked?  String, float, integer, list, what?

Comment: sorry, they are floats and integers

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `adult_pop` and the other population variables are not something that is subscriptable (i.e lists, tuples, dicts, etc) and are either ints or floats instead. That means you are trying to enter a type that does not allow that kind of examination, hence you are getting the error.

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not) will help you with subscriptablity.