# Python error with "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable."

Tags: python-3.x

What could the error with the code?

```
for i in range (1:100):  
    if(abs(sigmaList[i] - sigmaList[i-1]) < t_error):
     sigmaList = sigmaList[1:i] 
     break      
# Print the list of computed sigmas.
print(sigmaList)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991591/typeerror-float-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 0):

You will have error with `range (1:100)` - `SyntaxError` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)). Use `range(1,100)`.