# How to values a list of values from a dataframe? getting error 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble getting values from a dataframe I created from open weather data.

```
0                                 NaN
1        {'lon': -17.1, 'lat': 32.67}
2       {'lon': -73.36, 'lat': 41.14}
3       {'lon': 18.42, 'lat': -33.93}
4      {'lon': -53.81, 'lat': -29.68}
                    ...              
617     {'lon': -88.69, 'lat': 41.99}
618                               NaN
619    {'lon': -108.22, 'lat': 36.73}
620     {'lon': -73.58, 'lat': 40.66}
621      {'lon': 28.92, 'lat': 61.87}
Name: coord, Length: 622, dtype: object
```

I am attempting to get a list including only lat values. 
My initial thought has been to run a loop and append a list however I'm getting the error "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"

here is my code:

```
lat = []
for i in coord:
    lat.append(i['lat'])
```

desired output:

```
[32.67, 41.14, -33.93, -29.68, ..., 41.99, NaN, 36.73, 40.66, 61.87]
```

Comment: That's not a list, it's a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Your're right, I phrased that wrong any ideas regardless?

Comment: When you print `i`, what is it?

Comment: Same thing as the data I included except for the indexing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991591/typeerror-float-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```py
lat=coord.str["lat"]
lon=coord.str["lon"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of the rows of your dataframe just contain `NaN`, not a dictionary. You need to check for that.

```
import math

lat = []
for i in coord:
    if math.isnan(i):
        lat.append(NaN)
    else:
        lat.append(i['lat']
```

I'm not sure why you're putting dictionaries in a dataframe, it defeats the purpose of using pandas. You should make them separate columns in the df. Then you would be able to use:

```
lat = coords['lat'].tolist()
```

Comment: the data I'm pulling from has nested data and I was having trouble dealing with that I'll post a link to a separate question addressing that issue as this approach doesn't seem to be working.