# Python3 2D aray

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to print the row average for 2 rows from a standard input file using the redirection operator <.  The input will be [[99.0, 85.0, 98.0], [98.0, 57.0, 79.0]] The average should print to the right of the last column.   Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?  I will appreciate it!  When I run it, it is giving me an error " float object is not subscriptable".

```
import stdio

import stdarray

m = 2

n = 3

a = stdarray.create2D(m, n + 1, 0.0)

While not stdio.isEmpty():

    a = stdio.readFloat()

    for i in range(m):

        total = 0.0

        for j in range(n):

            total += a[i][j]

        a[i][4] = total / m

        stdio.writeln(str(a) + ' ')
```

Comment: What line is the error from? Chances are that there's something on that line that may not be recognized as float. See this question's answers that can give you ideas to solve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991591

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.  I appreciate it! The error is coming from total += a[i][j]

Comment: Can you type the command that you are typing to send the input to your program? Are you typing `echo "[[99.0 85.0 98.0], [98.0, 57.0, 79.0]]" | python3 yourprogram.py`?

Comment: python3 name of file < grades.txt

Comment: You were seeing the error because `while not stdio.isEmpty():` reads one float at a time. After `a = stdio.readFloat()` is executed, you'd get a float in `a` such as 99.0. `total += a[i][j]` is trying to treat 99.0 like an array, which it isn't. That's why you see the problem. The code in my answer stores floats one by one in an array.

Comment: Did you find the answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your grades.txt file look like this:

```
99.0 85.0 98.0
98.0 57.0 79.0
```

Try this code:

```
import stdio
import stdarray
import sys

m = 2
n = 3
a = stdarray.create2D(m, n + 1, 0.0)

row = 0
column = 0
total = 0.0

while not stdio.isEmpty():
    # read each float and store in input_text
    input_text = stdio.readFloat()

    # store the float in 0,0 first
    a[row][column] = input_text

    # before reading the next one, increment column
    # and add to the total
    column += 1
    total += input_text

    # if your column is now 3, it is time to switch to the next row
    # add total to the last column in the row
    # reset the total, reset the column and increment the row
    if column == n:
        a[row][column] = total/n
        total = 0
        column = 0
        row += 1

print(a)
```

Run like this:

```
python3 test.py < grades.txt
```

Result:

```
[[99.0, 85.0, 98.0, 94.0], [98.0, 57.0, 79.0, 78.0]]
```

stdio.py is https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/code/stdio.py

stdarray.py is https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/code/stdarray.py