# List of strings: Getting 'type error' float object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

```
str(datecol)
print (type(datecol[0]))
for i in datecol:
    year = i[0:4]

print (year)
```

I previously asked this question, and I thought I had fixed it by changing the type of my list to a list of strings. I printed out the types of each element, and it returned , however I still got the type error on the line `year = i[0:4]` . Any help would again be greatly appreciated! As well, I have tried using the datetime function but due to the nature of the data, it didn't work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991591/typeerror-float-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Comment: `row['DATE']` is a float - confirm with `print(type(row['DATE'])` - if not, make your example a [mre] and vote for reopening after [edit]ing it

Comment: If you type print(type(row['DATE'])) I am guessing the return value will be 'float'. Anything printed to the console is automatically coerced to a string but the underlying type is not necessarily string

Comment: If your dates are stored as floats, what you want to do with indexing them will not work.

Comment: Maybe it'd be helpful if you can provide a sample from your file? By the way is this on pandas? You may want to see [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert datetime