# Why am i getting a 'float' object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python

Im expecting to type the number of rows(students) and columns(quizzes) to define how many student take how many quizzes (matrix exactly).
So after i type the quiz marks for each student at each of their quiz, it is expected that i would get a calculation of each student average (exe:student1 avg = quiz1 + quiz2 +quiz3/3 and so on for student 2 and 3) and also get calculation of each quiz average (quiz1 avg = stu1+stu2+stu3/quiz and so on for quiz 2,3,4...)
But for now i didn't managed to get that as it shows i have a 'float' object is not subscriptable error. Why is that?
This is the full code

```
R = int(input("Enter the number of rows:"))
C = int(input("Enter the number of columns:"))


matrix = []
print("Enter the entries rowwise:")
for i in range(R):
    a = []
    for j in range(C):
         a.append(int(input("Student " + str(i+1) + " Quiz " + str(j+1)+":")))
    matrix.append(a)

for i in range(R):
    T1 = 0
    for j in range(C):
        T1 += matrix[i][j]
    matrix[i] = T1/C
    print()

for i in range(R):
    print("The average mark for student", i+1, "is", matrix[i])



for j in range(C):
    T2 = 0
    for i in range(R):
        T2 += matrix[i][j]  #This is where i get float object is not subscriptable error
    matrix[j] = T2/R
    print()

for j in range(C):
    print("The average mark for quiz", j+1, "is", int(matrix[j]))
```

Comment: It means that you are trying to index a float, for example `5.8[2]`

Comment: `matrix[i]` in that spot is a float

Comment: Sure, do you have a solution to fix that?

Comment: @F.M It's T2 which got the error, T1 which completely has the same function works well.

Comment: When you do `matrix[i] = T1/C`, how are you expecting that to work? Hint: what was the *type* of `matrix[i]` *before* the assignment? What is the type afterward? What is happening to your `matrix` as you do this to each row?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991591/typeerror-float-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Comment: I undid the duplicate closure (upon randomly reviewing the question over a year later), because OP's question doesn't seem to be about what the exception means, or why it isn't possible to subscript a `float`; it seems to be specifically about *why there is a `float` where something subscriptable was expected*. That said, it should probably be re-closed as a typo; the cause is an idiosyncratic logic error that should have been caught by [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Alternatively, close as a duplicate for the overall averaging task.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(R):
    T1 = 0
    for j in range(C):
        T1 += matrix[i][j]
    matrix[i] = T1/C
    print()
```

This process iteratively *replaces* each row (`matrix[i]`), which was a list, with a single number (the calculated average). So after the loop, we now have a 1D list, instead of a 2D list.

Therefore, when we try to add up the "columns" in the matrix the same way to get quiz averages, we have invalid data.

Bugfix: use a separate list to store the resulting averages. Alternately, you can `print` them as they are computed, instead of storing them anywhere.